# Custom ASP.NET Membership provider: can I put it in another project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I'm building a custom ASP.NET Membership provider since I'd like to use my own 'User' table for creating members and that kind of stuff. Here's the situation:

1. I've got a MVC 4 project that refers to a 'Services' project containing the service layer.
2. I built a wrapper around the custom MembershipProvider which helps unit testing. This wrapper references the custom MembershipProvider.
3. I reference the wrapper from my service layer.
4. I placed the custom MembershipProvider inside the MVC4 project (in the App_Data folder) because that's required as far as I know... At least: Visual Studio whines that it can't find the membership provider if I put it elsewhere.

So now I've got a circular dependency: MVC4 -> Service Layer -> Wrapper -> MVC4. My question: how do I get rid of that? Ideally I'd like to place the membership provider in a separate project, but I just don't get that to work. Any suggestions about that? Google isn't really helpful I'm afraid.

Bonus question 1: Should I extend SqlMembershipProvider instead of MembershipProvider?

Bonus question 2: Is there no better option? This whole ASP.NET membership feels really outdated and has many downsides imho (for instance: it isn't built to be testable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can absolutely put your custom membership provider in another project. I have two that I built as separate DLLs, and then added a reference in the web project.

You don't mention why you added a reference in your service layer, but if this is necessary you should really treat them as two different scopes, and therefore requiring two separate solutions. I have one membership provider that required calling a WCF service to authenticate membership, but those are two seperate pieces and you should not be sharing code between the two.

You do not need to place your code in the App_Data folder, just add a reference to your Membership Provider project or DLL in the web site project. Right

Bonus Question 1: No.

Bonus Question 2: The membership providers pre-date the whole TDD movement (as far as Microsoft is concerned), so yes, they are not real conducive to testing. But, if you inherit from the base classes, you are hooking into a well tested and time-worn framework, so you really only need to test your custom bits.